# How to check a new record inserted in MySQL table or not

Tags: php, android, mysql

I create two application in android :
1- One of them Insert data to MySQL in server.
2- Other One get new data from server.
also I create web services for inserting and selecting data from server. 
I want to get newest insert data (not all data in table) into app 2 but I don't Know how to do it.... Must create a new web service to handle this or coding in my app ?? thanks for help.

Comment: Sounds like you need a JSON API for your application. If you're using PHP, find a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that gets you closer to your goal.
[Laravel](http://laravel.com/) can be used to [quickly build out one](https://github.com/nilportugues/laravel5-jsonapi).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask Please take a look at how to ask a question. We're here to help, but we need informations. Provide some code or examples, otherwise we can't help you. Also, we're NOT here to give you advises of HOW doing something -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

You can have a id column with auto increment and when you query data query as : `SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

or

```
var_id=SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable
```

.

```
recordset=SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = var_id

or----

SQliteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, queryParameters);
```

and then acces data using loop